# How generate auto increment no with string value using Entity Framework in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0, .net-core-2.0

Is it possible to auto generate entity value using Entity Framework? For example a registration id such as `2015ACAD0001` - in this value, the first 4 digits show the year, the next 3 digits show any prefix according to requirement, and the remaining digits are auto increment no as per specific year and prefix

Comment: in my project i used code first approach for designing Database

Comment: Yes! Possible. It will take so much effort. I have done this in one my Enterprise Project.

Comment: Can you explain how? can first create specific string using c# are using Entity framework Automatically Created just like    Identity

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with a computed column:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
        .Property(p => p.RegistrationId)
        .HasComputedColumnSql([SQL HERE]);
}
```

How to calculate the exact id is on you. Generally-speaking, it just needs to be a SQL expression that evaluates to the type of the column you're computing for, in this case: a string.

Comment: can you sand any link for explanation of above example.